# How to get SSRS to display correct Hours Worked Avg when using all parameter options?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi Currently we have a report that shows the hours worked by employee per pay period.

It includes the following parameters the user can select:

```
   Period End From: Date
   Period End To: Date
   Company: (List of all companies inside Org) Use Select All
   Department: (List of all Departments) Use Select All
```

Example of Sample Output: I run the report from 9/7 to 10/5 and it takes the the Avg for that period.
[image: Sample Output]

Exactly what it is supposed to do and how I have it programmed.

But... Once I go back and rerun the report and change the Period End From Date to 8/24 it switches the Avg to be 51.10 in which it should be 63.88... Has anyone ran into this issue? 
[image: Example]

Here is my expression that I have for the light blue box for the hours worked:

```
=Sum(Fields!PP_HOURS.Value) / (Fields!PAY_PER_COUNT.Value)
```

Here is a sample of my SQL code

```
select p.EMPLOYEE
, p.PER_BEG_DATE
, p.PER_END_DATE
, (e.FTE_TOTAL * 80) as FTE
, sum(p.HOURS) as PP_HOURS
, (select sum(t2.the_count) from (select 1 as the_count from [dbo].[PR_PRTIME] p where p.PER_END_DATE >= (@PER_END_DATE_FROM) and p.PER_END_DATE <= (@PER_END_DATE_TO) and p.PROCESS_LEVEL IN (@PROCLEVEL) group by p.PER_END_DATE) as t2) as PAY_PER_COUNT
 from [dbo].[PR_PRTIME] p
```

Comment: Try dividing by `CountRows("DataSet Name")` this will give you the number of rows

Comment: @Diego in my query or in the expression?

Comment: In the expression.

Comment: @Diego are you saying: Sum(Fields!PP_HOURS.Value) / CountRows(Std_Hours) is my dateset?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to surround the DataSet in quotes ("Std_Hours"), I am not saying it will work, but it is worth a shot. Let me know if that works

Comment: @Diego hmm didn't seem to work. It now gave from the example above a value of 0.01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200969/discussion-between-mountaindewking-and-diego).

Comment: Maybe the query is incomplete, but it looks like you're only filtering between the dates for the `PAY_PER_COUNT` column and `PP_HOURS` seems to just `SUM` all the hours.  I'm guessing that could have something to do with why the averaging isn't working correctly, but it's hard to say for sure. On second look, the second result is dividing by 5, not 4.  Any duplicates in your results table?

Comment: @Steve-o169 I am not seeing any duplicates since it displays the values that need to be added and divided

Comment: My guess is that there are two entries for 8/24 that are being grouped together in the final result, but in the procedure, they are separate and are counted separately.  Could you try something like `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.PER_END_DATE) from [dbo].[PR_PRTIME] p where p.PER_END_DATE >= (@PER_END_DATE_FROM) and p.PER_END_DATE <= (@PER_END_DATE_TO) and p.PROCESS_LEVEL IN (@PROCLEVEL)`?

Comment: Could you not use the Average function for the field you bound to the Hours Worked column?  = AVG(Fields!HoursWorked,"DatasetName")

Comment: Your query only needs `PER_END_DATE` and ´PP_Hours`, and it should `GROUP BY PER_END_DATE` to calculate the sum. In the report, simply use the `Avg` function.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Are you saying to put that after the ,(select sum(t2.the_count) from (**Your Select Count Statement**

Comment: @WolfgangKais I just put the simplified query on here. In my actual query it groups by:  p.EMPLOYEE
 , p.PER_BEG_DATE
 , p.PER_END_DATE
 , e.PROCESS_LEVEL

Comment: You showed us your desired report and I told you what query you need. Maybe it's time to simplify your actual query.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Thanks for the response. I was able to correct the issue by using the Avg in my function.